# Using Parameters to Add Columns?

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure which adds a currency record to my exchange rate table but I also need a corresponding column for the added currency.

The table structure is as follows:

```
CurrencyID  CurrencyName Rupee                  Euro                   Dollar                 Pound
----------- ------------ ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
1           Rupee        1                      0.008                  0.009                  0.007
2           Euro         121.3                  1                      1.08                   0.84
3           Dollar       111.4                  0.91                   1                      0.77
4           Pound        143.6                  1.18                   1.28                   1
```

and my stored procedure so far is this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addCurrency 
    @CurrencyName varchar(30),
    @Rupee float,
    @Euro float,
    @Dollar float,
    @Pound float
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT into [dbo].[CurrencyTbl] (CurrencyName, Rupee, Euro, Dollar, Pound) 
    VALUES (@CurrencyName, @Rupee, @Euro, @Dollar, @Pound)
END
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000)

    SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CurrencyTbl] ADD ' + @CurrencyName + ' VARCHAR(30)'
END
```

But the column is not created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I think any of that is a good idea, but you do not actually execute your created `@SQL`, you are just selecting it.

Your code vulnerable to SQL Injection (because you are directly executing sql with concatenated parameters), so be careful with that code.

Also, if you are storing numbers, why is your datatype `varchar(30)`?  Your other datatypes are `float` (which should probably be a `numeric/decimal` instead of `float`).

You could use `exec sp_executesql @SQL` like so:

```
CREATE PROC addCurrency @CurrencyName  varchar(30),@Rupee float,
@Euro float,@Dollar float,@Pound float
    AS
    BEGIN
    INSERT into [dbo].[CurrencyTbl] (CurrencyName , Rupee,Euro, Dollar,Pound ) 
    VALUES (@CurrencyName,@Rupee,@Euro,@Dollar,@Pound )
    END
    BEGIN
    Declare @SQL nVarChar(1000)
    SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CurrencyTbl] ADD ' + @CurrencyName + ' float;'
    exec sp_executesql @SQL;
    END
```

dynamic sql

- [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)
- [**`sp_executesql`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

---

For example:

```
/* Monies is the term used by Irkens to refer to their form of currency */
exec addCurrency 'Monies',1,1,1,1 
select * from CurrencyTbl
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CUC99912

returns:

```
+------------+--------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
| CurrencyID | CurrencyName |   Rupee    |   Euro   |  Dollar  |  Pound   | Monies |
+------------+--------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
|          1 | Rupee        | 1,000000   | 0,008000 | 0,009000 | 0,007000 | NULL   |
|          2 | Euro         | 121,300000 | 1,000000 | 1,080000 | 0,840000 | NULL   |
|          3 | Dollar       | 111,400000 | 0,910000 | 1,000000 | 0,770000 | NULL   |
|          4 | Pound        | 143,600000 | 1,180000 | 1,280000 | 1,000000 | NULL   |
|          5 | Monies       | 1,000000   | 1,000000 | 1,000000 | 1,000000 | NULL   |
+------------+--------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
```

---

It may be better to consider an alternative form for your table that does not require adding new columns and updating columns using dynamic sql.

Here is one option:

```
create table CurrencyTbl (FromCurrencyName varchar(30), ExchangeRate decimal(19,6), ToCurrencyName varchar(30))
insert into CurrencyTbl values
 ('Rupee ',1.000000,'Rupee')
,('Rupee ',0.008000,'Euro')
,('Rupee ',0.009000,'Dollar')
,('Rupee ',0.007000,'Pound')
,('Euro  ',121.300000,'Rupee')
,('Euro  ',1.000000,'Euro')
,('Euro  ',1.090000,'Dollar')
,('Euro  ',0.850000,'Pound')
,('Dollar',111.400000,'Rupee')
,('Dollar',0.910000,'Euro')
,('Dollar',1.000000,'Dollar')
,('Dollar',0.770000,'Pound')
,('Pound ',143.600000,'Rupee')
,('Pound ',1.180000,'Euro')
,('Pound ',1.280000,'Dollar')
,('Pound ',1.000000,'Pound')
```

And you could pivot the table dynamically like so:

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max);
declare @sql  nvarchar(max);
  select @cols = stuff((
    select distinct 
      ', ' + quotename(ToCurrencyName)
      from CurrencyTbl
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,1,'')
select  @sql = '
 select FromCurrencyName as CurrencyName,' + @cols + '
  from CurrencyTbl
 pivot (max([ExchangeRate]) for [ToCurrencyName] in (' + @cols + ') ) p'
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/EQSC62833

returns:

```
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
| CurrencyName |  Dollar  |   Euro   |  Pound   |   Rupee    |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
| Dollar       | 1,000000 | 0,910000 | 0,770000 | 111,400000 |
| Euro         | 1,090000 | 1,000000 | 0,850000 | 121,300000 |
| Pound        | 1,280000 | 1,180000 | 1,000000 | 143,600000 |
| Rupee        | 0,009000 | 0,008000 | 0,007000 | 1,000000   |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Won't the CREATE PROC fail since the INSERT specifies a column that doesn't exist?

Comment: @RamblinRose It would if the insert specified a column that didn't exist, but it only specifies the same four that are in the table above: `Rupee,Euro, Dollar,Pound`

Comment: I'm only using `varchar(30)` for the name of the currency, My overall intention is to create another column from parameter , then populate its values after its is successfully created. Actually i see youre referring to my creating a new column withdatatype varchar. My bad

Comment: @RamblinRose Because `CurrencyName` is a column in the table.

Comment: @SqlZim How about adding values to the newly created column? Use dynamic sql again?

Comment: @GerMc You could, but it would be better to store all of this in a normalized table and either pivot in the front end application or use a dynamic pivot.

Comment: Ok, I havn't researched pivots before. I'm working on another query that adds values for each currency record just to get everything working.Care to explain where I'm wrong here? http://rextester.com/DLRAL6634

Comment: @GerMc You haven't said what it should be = to, and you will need to wrap rupee in single quotes. I edited your rextester, refresh to see the changes.

Comment: Is it possible to use the @Rupee parameter as a value instead? Im currenty getitng an error `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`

Comment: @GerMc Why do you keep asking me questions when you've marked the other answer as the answer?

Comment: Sorry, didnt realise I had

Comment: @GerMc The math doesn't quite work out precisely based on some issues from the example data, but you should be able to get the idea here: http://rextester.com/YRDB40508

Answer (score 1):

I created Temp Tables but this ought to work with standard ones as well...

```
CREATE TABLE #Currencies (
Currencyid INTEGER identity(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
,CurrencyName VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE TABLE #ConversionRates (
CurrencyId1 INTEGER
,CurrencyId2 INTEGER
,Conversion1To2Rate DECIMAL(19, 6)
)
```

Then we have a stored proc to handle the work

```
/************************************************************************************************
Stored Procedure: dbo.usp_AddCurrency
M. Jay Wheeler  -- mjwheele@yahoo.com
****************************************************************************************************/
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].usp_AddCurrency --
    @CurrencyName VARCHAR(255) = NULL
    ,@CurrencyId INTEGER = NULL
    ,@Currency2Id INTEGER = NULL
    ,@Currency1ToCurrency2ExchangeRate DECIMAL(19, 6) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @ThrowErrorOnAddingAlreadyExists CHAR(1) = 'N' -- If N will automatically update the currency Name.

    BEGIN TRY
        --#############################################################################
        -- Check Parameters
        --#############################################################################
        IF @CurrencyId IS NULL
            AND @CurrencyName IS NULL
            SELECT @ErrorMessage += '@CurrencyID and @CurrencyName cannot both be null.' + CHAR(13)

        IF @CurrencyId IS NULL
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #Currencies
                WHERE CurrencyName = @CurrencyName
                )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Currencies (CurrencyName)
            SELECT @CurrencyName

            SELECT @CurrencyId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        END

        SELECT @CurrencyId = CurrencyId
        FROM #Currencies
        WHERE CurrencyName = @CurrencyName
            AND @CurrencyId IS NULL

        SELECT @CurrencyName = CurrencyName
        FROM #Currencies
        WHERE Currencyid = @CurrencyId
            AND @CurrencyName IS NULL

        IF NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #Currencies
                WHERE Currencyid = @CurrencyId
                )
            SELECT @ErrorMessage += '@CurrencyID: ' + isnull(Cast(@CurrencyId AS VARCHAR(15)), 'NULL') + ' Does Not Exist.' + CHAR(13)

        IF EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #Currencies c
                WHERE c.Currencyid <> @CurrencyId
                    AND c.CurrencyName = @CurrencyName
                )
            SELECT @ErrorMessage += 'Currency: ' + @CurrencyName + ' already exists with an ID of ' + cast((
                        SELECT currencyId
                        FROM #Currencies
                        WHERE CurrencyName = @CurrencyName
                        ) AS VARCHAR(15)) + CHAR(13)

        IF EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #Currencies c
                WHERE c.Currencyid = @CurrencyId
                    AND c.CurrencyName <> @CurrencyName
                )
            UPDATE #Currencies
            SET CurrencyName = @CurrencyName
            WHERE Currencyid = @CurrencyId

        IF @Currency2Id IS NOT NULL
            AND @Currency1ToCurrency2ExchangeRate IS NULL
            SELECT @Errormessage += 'Improper Syntax no exchange rate to assignmen.' + CHAR(13)

        IF @Currency2id IS NULL
            AND @Currency1ToCurrency2ExchangeRate IS NOT NULL
            SELECT @Errormessage += 'Improper Syntax no "To Currency" for rate assignment.' + CHAR(13)

        IF len(@ErrorMessage) > 0
         RAISERROR ('%s' ,16 ,1 ,@ErrorMessage)

        --#############################################################################
        -- you get the idea more error checking needed to bullet proof.  Now assume
        -- We have all the correct Parameters set up, we've made sure anything coming in
        -- needs to be added or updated by this point.
        --#############################################################################
        --#############################################################################
        -- nothing to do if @Currency2Id is null
        --#############################################################################
        IF @Currency2Id IS NULL
            RETURN

        --#############################################################################
        -- see if we need to add/Update a conversion rate.
        --#############################################################################
        UPDATE #ConversionRates
        SET Conversion1To2Rate = @Currency1ToCurrency2ExchangeRate
        WHERE @CurrencyId = CurrencyId1
            AND @Currency2Id = CurrencyId2

        INSERT INTO #ConversionRates (
            CurrencyId1
            ,CurrencyId2
            ,Conversion1To2Rate
            )
        SELECT @CurrencyId
            ,@Currency2Id
            ,@Currency1ToCurrency2ExchangeRate
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #ConversionRates
                WHERE @CurrencyId = CurrencyId1
                    AND @Currency2Id = CurrencyId2
                )
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@Trancount > 0
            ROLLBACK TRAN

        DECLARE @ErrorBlockLineLen INTEGER = 0
        DECLARE @ErrorBlockGotTheFormat BIT = 0
        DECLARE @ErrorFormatIndent INTEGER = 3
        DECLARE @ErrorBlockBeenThrough INTEGER = NULL -- must be set to null
        DECLARE @ThisProcedureName VARCHAR(255) = ISNULL(OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID), 'Testing')
        DECLARE @ErrorProc VARCHAR(4000) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000), ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), @ThisProcedureName))

        WHILE @ErrorBlockGotTheFormat = 0
        BEGIN
            IF @ErrorBlockBeenThrough IS NOT NULL
                SELECT @ErrorBlockGotTheFormat = 1

            SET @errormessage = Space(isnull(@ErrorFormatIndent, 0)) + @ThisProcedureName + ' Reports Error Thrown by: ' + @ErrorProc + CHAR(13)
            SET @errormessage += Space(isnull(@ErrorFormatIndent, 0)) + '-------->' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000), ERROR_MESSAGE()), 'Unknown') + '<--------' + CHAR(13) --               + Space(isnull(@ErrorFormatIndent,0)) + REPLICATE('=', @ErrorBlockLineLen) + CHAR(13) --               + Space(isnull(@ErrorFormatIndent,0)) + UPPER(@ThisProcedureName + ' Variable dump:') + CHAR(13) --               + Space(isnull(@ErrorFormatIndent,0)) + REPLICATE('=', @ErrorBlockLineLen) + CHAR(13) --
                + CHAR(13) + Space(isnull(@ErrorFormatIndent, 0)) + '@Currency1ToCurrency2ExchangeRate:.....<' + ISNULL(CAST(@Currency1ToCurrency2ExchangeRate AS VARCHAR(25)), 'Null') + '>' + CHAR(13) + SPACE(ISNULL(@ErrorBlockBeenThrough, 0)) --
                + CHAR(13) + Space(isnull(@ErrorFormatIndent, 0)) + '@Currency2Id:..........................<' + ISNULL(CAST(@Currency2Id AS VARCHAR(25)), 'Null') + '>' + CHAR(13) + SPACE(ISNULL(@ErrorBlockBeenThrough, 0)) --
                + CHAR(13) + Space(isnull(@ErrorFormatIndent, 0)) + '@CurrencyId:...........................<' + ISNULL(CAST(@CurrencyId AS VARCHAR(25)), 'Null') + '>' + CHAR(13) + SPACE(ISNULL(@ErrorBlockBeenThrough, 0)) --
                + CHAR(13) + Space(isnull(@ErrorFormatIndent, 0)) + '@CurrencyName:.........................<' + ISNULL(CAST(@CurrencyName AS VARCHAR(25)), 'Null') + '>' + CHAR(13) + SPACE(ISNULL(@ErrorBlockBeenThrough, 0)) --

            --SELECT @ErrorBlockLineLen = MAX(LEN(RTRIM(item)))
            --FROM dbo.fnSplit(@errormessage, CHAR(13))
             SELECT @ErrorBlockLineLen = 120

            SELECT @ErrorBlockBeenThrough = 1
        END

             RAISERROR ('%s' ,16 ,1 ,@ErrorMessage)

    END CATCH
END
GO
```

And this is the code to populate.  I used the inverse for some of the rates as it was easier.

```
set nocount on

exec usp_AddCurrency 'Rupiee'
exec usp_AddCurrency 'Euro'
exec usp_AddCurrency 'Dollar'
exec usp_AddCurrency 'Pound'


exec usp_AddCurrency "Rupiee", Null, 1, 1.000000
exec usp_AddCurrency "Rupiee", Null, 2, 0.008000
exec usp_AddCurrency "Rupiee", Null, 3, 0.009000
exec usp_AddCurrency "Rupiee", Null, 4, 0.007000   

Declare @Inverse Decimal(19,6)
Select @Inverse =  cast ((1.000000/ (Select Conversion1To2Rate From #ConversionRates Where CurrencyId1 = 1 and CurrencyId2 =2 )) as decimal(19,6))
exec usp_AddCurrency 'Euro'   , Null, 1, @Inverse
exec usp_AddCurrency 'Euro'   , Null, 2, 1.000000
exec usp_AddCurrency 'Euro'   , Null, 3, 1.090000
exec usp_AddCurrency 'Euro'   , Null, 4, 0.850000


Select @Inverse =  cast ((1.000000/ (Select Conversion1To2Rate From #ConversionRates Where CurrencyId1 = 1 and CurrencyId2 =3 )) as decimal(19,6))
exec usp_AddCurrency 'Dollar' , Null, 1,@Inverse
Select @Inverse =  cast ((1.000000/ (Select Conversion1To2Rate From #ConversionRates Where CurrencyId1 = 2 and CurrencyId2 =3 )) as decimal(19,6))
exec usp_AddCurrency 'Dollar' , Null, 2, @Inverse
exec usp_AddCurrency 'Dollar' , Null, 3, 1.000000
exec usp_AddCurrency 'Dollar' , Null, 4, 0.770000

Select @Inverse =  cast ((1.000000/ (Select Conversion1To2Rate From #ConversionRates Where CurrencyId1 = 1 and CurrencyId2 =4 )) as decimal(19,6))
exec usp_AddCurrency 'Pound'  , Null, 1, @Inverse
Select @Inverse =  cast ((1.000000/ (Select Conversion1To2Rate From #ConversionRates Where CurrencyId1 = 2 and CurrencyId2 =4 )) as decimal(19,6))
exec usp_AddCurrency 'Pound'  , Null, 2, @Inverse
Select @Inverse =  cast ((1.000000/ (Select Conversion1To2Rate From #ConversionRates Where CurrencyId1 = 3 and CurrencyId2 =4 )) as decimal(19,6))
exec usp_AddCurrency 'Pound'  , Null, 3, @Inverse
exec usp_AddCurrency 'Pound'  , Null, 4, 1.000000
```

This is the end of your question I think.
I tested the output with this code:

```
Declare @MySQL nVarChar(max) = 'Create Table ##output ([Currency Name] Varchar(255),' + char(13)

SELECT @MySQL += STUFF(( SELECT  ',[' + CurrencyName + '] VARCHAR(255) '
                FROM    #Currencies 
       order by Currencyid asc
              FOR
                XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, '') + ')'


exec sp_executesql @MySQL

select * into #output from ##output
Drop Table ##Output


Declare @PivotThings varchar(max)


select @PivotThings = STUFF(( SELECT  ',[' + CurrencyName + ']  '
                FROM    #Currencies 
       order by Currencyid asc
              FOR
                XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, '')

Select @MySQL = '
 SELECT *
FROM(
  select c1.CurrencyName  as Rows, c1.Currencyid as r,  c2.CurrencyName as Cols,   Conversion1To2Rate as [Value] from #ConversionRates r
join #Currencies c1 on c1.Currencyid = r.CurrencyId1
join #Currencies c2 on c2.Currencyid = r.CurrencyId2
) WorkOrders
PIVOT
(
  SUM(value)
  FOR [cols] IN (
    ##PivotThings##
    ) 

) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY [r] 
'


Select @MySQL = REPLACE(@mysql , '##PivotThings##', @pivotthings)

exec sp_executesql @mysql
```

Hope you find this useful.  It is my first post evah!